# How to change sendmail fallback behavior if TLS handshake fails?

Tags: centos, email, smtp, sendmail, tls

I have a CentOS 5.x server running sendmail that is failing to negotiate TLS with SOME various recipient servers. I'm looking into it.

In the meantime though, I've noticed that sendmail will NOT bother falling back to use standard unencrypted delivery methods if TLS handshake errors occur.  Is this normal behavior?

I would expect this logic to be in place if (and only if) I explicitly required it for domains. For example if I added TLS_SRV options in /etc/mail/access.  In this case, I don't.  In essence, Sendmail is only running "opportunistic TLS".

All of the information I’ve come across thus far suggests that this issue is expected behavior and is hard-coded…

As per http://www.sendmail.org/m4/starttls.html#disable_starttls :

> By default STARTTLS is used whenever
>   possible. However, there are some
>   broken MTAs that don't properly
>   implement STARTTLS. To be able to send
>   to (or receive from) those MTAs, the
>   ruleset try_tls (srv_features) can be
>   used that work together with the
>   access map. Entries for the access map
>   must be tagged with Try_TLS
>   (Srv_Features) and refer to the
>   hostname or IP address of the
>   connecting system.

As per http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+II+Administration/Chapter+10.+Maintain+Security+with+sendmail/10.10+STARTTLS/:

> If the access database is not used,
>   the connection is allowed in all
>   cases, both inbound and outbound,
>   unless the value in ${verify} is
>   SOFTWARE, in which instance the
>   connection is not allowed.

Both of these blurbs suggest that the try_tls feature is the only option for skipping TLS when the other side claims to support it.  I understand that this is an option but it's cumbersome because it means I'd need to manually make exceptions anytime an outbound domain has trouble.

Is there any other way to have sendmail fallback?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error message that you see in the log file (if any) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.mail.sendmail/Vxdd3lrBQ04), the fallback feature `tls_failures` was [implemented in this patch](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/patches/tls_failures.p1). Apparently this will use plain text automatically after a certain number of TLS handshake failures.

> Note: this patch is integrated in 8.16 (at least available as snapshot)

As of this post, 8.16 is not yet [released](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/download/), so for now you will have to use `/etc/mail/access` or `/etc/mail/access_db` as [Seth suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/254364/how-to-change-sendmail-fallback-behavior-if-tls-handshake-fails#273335), and be sure to rebuild the `.db` using `makemap hash /etc/mail/access < /etc/mail/access`

As for security risks of using `tls_failures` globally; considering that this is [opportunistic TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS) to begin with, I think that refraining from using this new option would only help in some really fringe cases where the recipient mailserver is temporarily reconfigured and later corrected.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable TLS for certain hosts.  For example:

```
# Try_TLS:gmail.com                     NO
```

I also point you to http://www.sendmail.org/m4/starttls.html

---

Disabling STARTTLS And Setting SMTP Server Features

By default STARTTLS is used whenever possible. However, there are some broken MTAs that don't properly implement STARTTLS. To be able to send to (or receive from) those MTAs, the ruleset try_tls (srv_features) can be used that work together with the access map. Entries for the access map must be tagged with Try_TLS (Srv_Features) and refer to the hostname or IP address of the connecting system. A default case can be specified by using just the tag. For example, the following entries in the access map:

```
Try_TLS:broken.server   NO
Srv_Features:my.domain  v
Srv_Features:       V
```

will turn off STARTTLS when sending to broken.server (or any host in that domain), and request a client certificate during the TLS handshake only for hosts in my.domain. The valid entries on the RHS for Srv_Features are listed in the "Sendmail Installation and Operations Guide".